# Installing and running a maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jreddit

After 2 days searching around the web for  tutorials on running maven on intellij , I didn't find much and all the tutorial I tried returned some error ,

So can someone give me a step by step installation process on how to install maven on mac OS 10.10 using intellij and running a sample project using the maven pom file.

I believe this will help many others including me

after running :

> sudo mvn clean install

The error i received is

> *Error:java: directory not found: /Users/stingray/Documents/workspace/jreddit/target/generated-sources/annotations*

Comment: Can you post the "same error" that you got?

Comment: Installing. Download Maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.html and unpack and put it into the path.